# PHP/PostGres regexp to match only if a word in the string has 2 or more capitals, and only has letters

Tags: php, regex, postgresql

This seems like a simple expression, but all of my tinkering has failed in one place or another.  I am pulling data out of a PostgreSQL database.  I would rather filter in PostgreSQL, but if I need to do it in PHP that is fine too.  The column will have a string, and I need to search for matches where any word (defined by spaces) has two or more capital letters.  If I need to just explode each string and parse the "words" individually, I can do that too, but it seems like a regexp would be a much better way.

**Here are some examples :**

"The Quick Brown" //No Match
"The QuicK Brown" //MATCH (note QuicK has 2 caps in it)
"THE QUICK BROWN" //Match
"The QUICK1 Brown" //No Match (QUICK is all caps, but it has a non alpha character too)
"The QUICK BROWN1" //Match because QUICK is a hit even though BROWN1 is not.
"tHe qUick bRown" //No Match
"The QUICK-BROWN" //No Match (because - is non alpha, and words are only defined by space)
"the quick brown" //No Match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(^| )[A-Za-z]*[A-Z][A-Za-z]*[A-Z][A-Za-z]*( |$)
```

Checked via http://regexr.com?2sdi4